# How to sort multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have 100 data dataframes in R and would like to sort each of them by a column prior to using rbind to combine the dataframes.

I can use `data <- data[order(data$V2),]` for a small number of dataframes but I am unable to automate the process for hundreds of dataframes using loops (or another helpful construct).

I intend to use `x <- grep("data\\d",ls(),perl=TRUE,value=TRUE)` and `do.call(rbind, lapply(x, get))` to combine the sorted dataframes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `pattern` argument in `ls` to return the object names, wrap it with `mget` and it will get the values of the objects in a `list`.

```
 lst <- mget(ls(pattern='data\\d'))
```

We loop through the `list` elements with `lapply` and `order` using the 'V2' column (assuming that the column exist in all the datasets)

```
 lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[order(x$V2),])
```

---

If we want to change the original data object (not recommended as most of the operations can be done within the `list` environment), we can use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Or we can `rbind` all the datasets

```
df1 <- do.call(rbind, lst1)
```

It may be better to read all the datasets in a `list` directly rather than creating individual objects.  Suppose, if we want to read all the files in the working directory,

```
files <- list.files()
lst <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Works wonderfully thank you. Just one thing, for this example the `list2env` alternative should be `list2env(lst1, envir=.GlobalEnv)` not `lst`